# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (UserModel, ?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, nestjs

my user.module.ts:

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AuthModule } from 'src/auth/auth.module';


@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: 'User', schema: UserSchema}]),AuthModule],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

my auth.module.ts

```
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UsersModule), PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

my app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';


@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule,MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/nest1')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this are giving me error:

> [12:55:42 pm] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
>
> [Nest] 15944  - 20/09/2021, 12:55:45 pm     LOG [NestFactory] Starting
> Nest application... [Nest] 15944  - 20/09/2021, 12:55:45 pm     LOG
> [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +126ms [Nest]
> 15944  - 20/09/2021, 12:55:46 pm   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't
> resolve dependencies of the UsersService  (UserModel, ?). Please make
> sure that the argument AuthService at index [1] is available in the
> UsersModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If AuthService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
> - If AuthService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing AuthService */ ]   })
>
> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (UserModel,
> ?). Please make sure that the argument AuthService at index [1] is
> available in the UsersModule context.
>
> Potential solutions:
>
> - If AuthService is a provider, is it part of the current UsersModule?
> - If AuthService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within UsersModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing AuthService */ ]   })
>
>   at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:193:19)
>   at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:149:33)
>   at resolveParam (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:103:38)
>   at async Promise.all (index 1)
>   at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:118:27)
>   at Injector.loadInstance (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:47:9)
>   at Injector.loadProvider (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:69:9)
>   at async Promise.all (index 3)
>   at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:44:9)
>   at C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\BILDEMP\ems-by-nestjs\employee-management-system\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\instance-loader.js:29:13

Comment: I mean, I have no experience with nest.js but the error specifically says, "Please make sure that the argument AuthService at index [1] is available in the UsersModule context" so put `AuthService` somewhere in your user.module.ts. Probably in the `providers` array after the `UsersService`

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to make some assumptions about your service constructors, as you haven't provided those:

You have what looks to be a circular reference between the `UserModule` and the `AuthModule`. Because of this, in the `imports` of each module you need to use `forwardRef` of the module you're importing.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => UserModule), ...rest],
  providers,
  controllers,
  exports
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

```js
@Module({
  imports: [forwardRef(() => AuthModule), ...rest],
  providers,
  controllers,
  exports
})
export class UserModule {}
```

And speaking of `exports` above, you need to export a provider if you plan to use it outside of the module where it is in the `providers` (e.g. to use `AuthService` inside of `UserService`, the `AuthModule` needs to have `providers: [AuthService]` **and** `exports: [AuthService]`. This makes the provider available elsewhere.

Now, to make use of circular dependencies inside of the services, you also need to make use of `forwardRef`. In this case it will look like `@Inject(forwardRef(() => OtherClass)) private readonly other: OtherClass`, so you'd have something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthService)) private readonly auth: AuthService,
    private readonly dep2: DependencyClass2
  ) {}

  // rest of values
}
```

You'll do the same thing in the `AuthService` but replacing `AuthService` in the `@Inject()` with `UserService`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import all the dependencies of UserService in UserModule. If you still can't figure out then please also add your user.service.ts file in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the auth service in the authmodule in order to be able to inject it in the user service.